# Mongo greater than comparison returns 0

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to count all car dealers who's total fleet units is over 1000. This is the code I wrote to do it, however, it returns 0 and I know for a fact there are quite a few records in this data set that are over 1000.

```
db.Car_Dealership.find({Totalfleetunits : {$gte: 1000} }).count()
```

This is a sample of what's in my database, both records have total fleets over 1000. Any ideas why it returns 0?

```
     "_id" : ObjectId("5a203ab0b9574375830354d4"),
        "2016rank" : 6,
        "Dealershipgroupname" : "Hendrick Automotive Group",
        "Address" : "6000 Monroe Road",
        "City/State/Zip" : "Charlotte, NC 28212",
        "Phone" : "(704) 568-5550",
        "Companywebsite" : "www.hendrickauto.com",
        "Topexecutive" : "Rick Hendrick",
        "Topexecutivetitle" : "chairman",
        "Totalnewretailunits" : "117,946",
        "Totalusedunits" : "88,458",
        "Totalfleetunits" : "4,646",
        "Totalwholesaleunits" : "56,569",
        "Total_units" : "267,619",
        "Total_number_of _dealerships" : 103,
        "Grouprevenuealldepartments*" : "$8,551,253,132",
        "2015rank" : 6
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a203ab0b9574375830354d5"),
        "2016rank" : 5,
        "Dealershipgroupname" : "Sonic Automotive Inc.?",
        "Address" : "4401 Colwick Road",
        "City/State/Zip" : "Charlotte, NC 28211",
        "Phone" : "(704) 566-2400",
        "Companywebsite" : "www.sonicautomotive.com",
        "Topexecutive" : "B. Scott Smith",
        "Topexecutivetitle" : "CEO",
        "Totalnewretailunits" : "134,288",
        "Totalusedunits" : "119,174",
        "Totalfleetunits" : "1,715",
        "Totalwholesaleunits" : "35,098",
        "Total_units" : "290,275",
        "Total_number_of _dealerships" : 112,
        "Grouprevenuealldepartments*" : "$9,731,778,000",
        "2015rank" : 4
```

Comment: Can you post your schema here?

Comment: how can you compare string to number? mongodb is not javascript

Comment: Ya that's the problem. but anyway we can you `javascript` inside `query`. :)

Comment: yes but that is the super slow option you have, try to update your schema instead

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the value of `Totalfleetunits` is `stringType`.

Now to solve your problem you have to options.

### option 1:

You can change your schema for `Totalfleetunits` to the type of `Number` and change all the documents `Totalfleetvalues` value from string to a number. Like,

> "Totalfleetunits": "4,646" needs to be changed with "Totalfleetunits"
>   : "4646"

### option 2:

You can use `javascript` in your query to first remove `,` from your value then check the `Totalfleetunits` value for `greater than or equal to ( >= )`. Only need to change a single line of code as I given below.

```
db.Car_Dealership.find("this.Totalfleetunits.replace(',','') >= 1000").count()
```

Comment: I receive an error saying that replace is not a function

Comment: Yeah I am able to write javascript in mongo

Comment: No, it says  this.Totalfleetunits.replace is not a function